# webkit overflow scrolling touch conflicts with webkit transform

Tags: iphone, css, mobile-safari, mobile-webkit

It seems like applying a `webkit-transform` property on an element or it's parent that has `webkit-over-flowing-scrolling: touch` completely breaks the scrolling in that scrolling doesn't work at all.

Has anyone experienced this bug and know of a solution?

Answer (score 0):

My current (hacky) solution looks like this:

```
$container.one 'webkitAnimationEnd', ->
  $container.find('.contents').remove()
  $container.append('.contents')
```

Basically i'm removing and then re-adding the contents of the scrollable div after the animation ends. Hopefully someone has a better solution for this.

Answer (score 0):

I'm having the exact same problem, and it only goes away if I ditch `-webkit-transform` and switch to absolute positioning.

This would be fine, except that absolute positioning leads to lousy performance and choppy animation on iOS, which in iOS 6+ cannot be remedied w/ the previously popular `translateZ` and `translate3D` forced hardware acceleration hacks.

I figured out a hack, but it is so hideous and actually ugly that you might not want to read any further:

Take the element we want to apply `-webkit-overflow-scrolling:touch` to and separate it completely from the element we are applying `-webkit-transform` to. Use `z-index` manipulation to cause the scrolling element to appear in the same place it would have originally, while retaining `-webkit-transform` to cause the original container (now an empty container) to animate into place naturally. In my case this hack falls short though, because the scrollable content will appear suddenly on top of the animated container, instead of sliding in along with it.